# Zend Framework - Zend_Measure translation problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, translation, measurement

I want to translate measurements that Zend_Measure returns.
Something like:

10 hours (en_US)

in my language

10 часа (bg - Bulgarian)

I found out that there is an archive with translations that i need - Zend/Locale/Data
There are a bunch of .xml files, many of them have translations for measurements.

My idea is to use them to translate Zend_Measure measurement types. (After all these translations must be used for something...)

Can anyone help me :?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate or convert the style of an output like a date a curency or a number to a localized version you have to use zend locale. Zend locale will use those xml files and do the job for you. You don't need to grad the data in xml files and to it manually.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.date.datesandtimes.html